# Spring override bean of another module

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

In my multimodule project I have integration tests as seperate module. That tests have application jar added as dependency. Is it possible to override application bean definition from integration tests?

In application I have following Bean (standard java mail sender configuration)

```
@Configuration
public class MailConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public JavaMailSender javaMailService() {
      JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
      //standard mail configuration using properties
   }
}
```

Now all my integration tests extends BaseIntegrationTest that loads test configuration classess

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AppTestConfiguration.class, MailTestConfiguration.class})
public class BaseIntegrationTest {

}
```

And finally in my MailTestConfiguration I define another JavaMailSender

```
@Primary
@Bean
@Profile(TestProfiles.MAIL_GREEN_SMTP)
public JavaMailSender javaMailService() {

    JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    javaMailSender.setHost("localhost");
    javaMailSender.setPort(3025);

    return javaMailSender;
}
```

It is working when I run the tests from application itself. When I run the tests from another module the bean is not overriden.

I am aware that AppConfiguration class defined inside application cannot component scan the integration tests config classes so I also load AppTestConfiguration.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"..."})
public class AppTestConfiguration extends AppConfiguration {

}
```

How to make it work?

Comment: Are you loading the correct profiles in the sub test classes? Also, I would move runwith and webappconfiguration to the sub test classes to avoid any nasty inheritance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two things you should check:**

1. Is the right Spring profile enabled when you run the tests from another module?
2. Is the given configuration in the scan path when you run the tests from another module?

Answer (score 0):

Sure I messed up with profiles. In my BaseIntegrationTest I defined active profile based on configuration. I also printed which profile gets resolved there (correct profile name was printed)

```
    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        System.setProperty(DEFAULT_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME, ProfileResolver.getActiveProfiles());
    }
```

After you convinced me that it should work I rechecked the config and found that I also added spring.profiles.active in properties. After deleting this config everything work as expected. The other way is to use `AbstractEnvironment.ACTIVE_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME` instead of `AbstractEnvironment.DEFAULT_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME`